# Snowflake is converting json column into random string when loading an avro file

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, avro, snowflake-stage

I am trying to load an avro file into snowflake and parse the data. I am able to parse the file just fine in python, however snowflake is converting the Body column into a random string.

This is how each row looks in python.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RjzTo.png)

However, when I try to parse the file in snowflake, the body column is transformed into a random string. Am I missing something?

```
with cte as(
Select $1 as a from @stage_dev/test.avro
)
Select TOP 1
       a,
       a:SequenceNumber,
       a:Offset,
       a:EnqueuedTimeUtc,
       a:SystemProperties,
       a:Properties,
       a:Body
from cte a;
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2xGma.png)